# MAMP virtual hosts not working when connected to home network

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have virtual hosts setup on my laptop, which I know work fine as I use them often for work and school, but for whatever reason when I'm at my parents house connected to their home network I get 404'd. If I disconnect form the network I get servered the page fine by Apache. Here is my httpd.conf file contents (only the portion dealing with virtual hosts):

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/kyle/Sites/ESA/app/public"
    ServerName esa.loc
    <Directory "/Users/kyle/Sites/ESA/app/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/kyle/Sites/portfolio-site/public"
    ServerName kyle.loc
    <Directory "/Users/kyle/Sites/portfolio-site/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my /etc/hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost esa.loc kyle.loc
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost esa.loc kyle.loc
fe80::1%lo0     localhost esa.loc kyle.loc
```

If you need anymore information let me know and I'll do my best to provide it. Thanks.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I tried adding my laptop to the DMZ on the router but that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm really not sure, but shouldn't Virtualhost contain some information about port? Sth like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

I think you can remove these lines because it is useless in your case

```
NameVirtualHost *

Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

It does not make any sense to use ip address in "Allow" when you use "allow from all" on the line above

Answer (score 35):

Make sure you uncomment the line

## Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

In your apache conf file.

Comment: I guess the path is " conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf".